# Request types on iPhone || Android?

Tags: iphone, android

Is it possible to send GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests from iPhone || Android applications to a third party server?

I want to build a web service to reuse on all 3 platforms (3rd being the web app itself).

Comment: Yes NSURLConnection or  ASIHTTPRequest is what I would recommend for the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, making HTTP requests on mobile devices running iOS or Android is no different from desktop Java or Cocoa. Both platforms offer API's that enable you to change the request method. Checkout `NSURLConnection` on iOS and the `org.apache.http` package on Android.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's all possible on both iOS and Android OS platforms, however while designing web service, you probably may consider a lightweight implementation as mobile platforms are not powerful enough if you for example intend to use SOAP extensively. My most often choice is REST+JSON.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how to implement a webservice call in android:

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/